# Find minimum moves to transform one number to another

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, binary

Suppose we are given two positive integers, $a$ and $b$. Each move we are allowed to divide $a$ by 2 (but only if $a$ is even), multiply $a$ by 2, or add 1 to $a$. How many moves does it take to change $a$ to $b$? Find either a direct formula or an efficient algorithm for this.

Some progress that I have made: We can think of it as writing $b=2^ka+\text{something}$, where this "something" can be expressed by the sum of powers of 2 (including negative exponents). Clearly we'd want to choose $k$ so that $k$ is a large as possible while maintaining $2^ka<b$, and we'd want $k$ to be the total difference between the $\times 2$s and the $\div 2$s. However I'm not too sure how to go from here. Does someone have solution?

Comment: Suppose $a=1, b=15$. A naive approach might be to do: $1\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2+1+1+1+1+1+1+1$. But, it is faster to use $(1\cdot 2+1)\cdot 2\cdot 2+1+1+1$. It is a difference of 10 operations to keep multiplying by 2 then add one repeatedly to reach the end number vs 7 if you multiply by 2, then add one, then multiply by 2 twice more, then add 1 three more times. I am not sure what a solution would look like, but it does not involve starting with repeated multiplication by 2.

Comment: @above add 1 to $a$ and divide by two...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Represent both numbers in binary. Your objective is to match the binary "patern". In one step you may:

- Remove $0$ from the end of $a$
- Add $0$ to the end of $a$
- Convert $0$ at the end of $a$ into $1$

Try to do by hand for some small numbers first e.g. $a=6$ and $b=17$